# NSTimer and performing a selector on the main thread

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to run a selector which is invoked by the nstimer on the main thread?

The NSTimer is spawned in it's own thread.

My structure is that a thread invokes a method with a nstimer, the nstimer invokes a method that do some updates, but I need these updates to happen on the main thread. What is the solution? Add another method and say `performOnMainThread`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, from your timer routine just call use performOnMainThread.   From the docs:

> Timers work in conjunction with run
>   loops. To use a timer effectively, you
>   should be aware of how run loops
>   operate—see NSRunLoop and Threading
>   Programming Guide. Note in particular
>   that run loops retain their timers, so
>   you can release a timer after you have
>   added it to a run loop.

also a caveat about invalidating repeating timers:

> for a repeating timer, you must
>   invalidate the timer object yourself
>   by calling its invalidate method.
>   Calling this method requests the
>   removal of the timer from the current
>   run loop; as a result, you should
>   always call the invalidate method from
>   the same thread on which the timer was
>   installed